# decompressing video on different platforms, value of pixels differ

Tags: python, swift, opencv, video-processing, cvpixelbuffer

I got the wrong pixel values between Swift iOS and OpenCV Python.

In Python, I read video with `video.read()` and got BGR `79, 82, 90` of the first pixel.

In Swift, I read the video by `AVURLAsset` and I got BGR `80, 84, 92`.

It seems quite the same, but maybe there's some rounding here, isn't there?
How can I deal with it? I really appreciate your help.

Here is some code to reproduce:

**Python:**

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('test_video.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()

image[0][0] # output is [79, 82, 90]
```

**Swift:**

```
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
        while reader?.status == AVAssetReader.Status.reading {
            if(rout.copyNextSampleBuffer() != nil){
                // Buffer of the frame to perform processing on
                let sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer = rout.copyNextSampleBuffer()!
                let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            }
            usleep(10000)
        }
    })
```

Extract pixel from first `pixelBuffer` and I got BGR `[80, 84, 92]`

Comment: a [mre] must include the data required to run it. -- video compression is usually lossy. different decoders may produce different outputs. additionally, color space transforms may happen, or not.